# Mocking a dependency that is not visible outside

Tags: junit, mockito

I have to unit test some old code that wasn't designed to support unit testing (No DI). Is there a way to mock an object that is being initialized within a public method?

```
public int method() {

    A a = new A(ar1, arg2); //How to mock this?

}
```

Thanks,

-Abidi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to refactor the code into

```
public int method() {
   A a = createA(arg1,arg2);
}

A createA(int arg1, int arg2) {
    return new A(arg1,arg2);
}
```

In your test method now you can use Mockito's `spy` and `doAnswer` functions to override `createA` on your test fixture with something along the lines of:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Foo spiedFoo = spy(foo); // a spied version when you can copy the behaviour
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock inv) throws Throwable {
        A a = mock(A.class);
        return a;
    }
}).when(mySpy).createA(anyInt(), anyInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the code in question, you can refactor it and make the dependency public, for example by depending on some A-builder. This is probably the best solution, since it makes your class less dependent on `A`. [Forcing you to decouple your design is one of the main advantages of testing.]